# Find element by XPATH via LXML - Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am having some problems with scraping some web data using LXML.
I want to scrape one thing from a website using BeautifulSoup so I decided I would go with LXML. I wrote some code and got the Discord Bot to access the website. Now the only thing left is to code finding those elemenents.
Here is my code, help would be appreciated.

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds = 10)
    async def exchangeRate(self):
        print("Loop Starting!")
        HEADERS = {
            'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"
        }

        url = 'https://rubyrealms.com/economy/bank'

        async with aiohttp.request("GET", url, headers=HEADERS) as response:
            if response.status == 200:
                #Scrape page content into one variable
                content = await response.text()
                #Initialize soup
                soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
                #Request access to site
                page = requests.get(url)
                #Declaring "tree" - Used to scrape by XPATH
                tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
                stuff = tree.xpath('//*[@id="content-wrap"]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/h4')
                print(stuff)

            else:
                print(f"The request was invalid\nStatus code: {response.status}")
```

This is my task loop for Discord.Py ReWrite, basically every 10 seconds it gets access to the site. As shown the following code works, just besides:

```py
stuff = tree.xpath('//*[@id="content-wrap"]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/h4')
print(stuff)
```

The only thing it prints is "Loop Starting!" from the beginning of the loop. With that code above (The long one) I get printed out this:

```
Bot is ready for duty!
Exchange Cog is ready!
Waiting for loop!
Loop Starting!
[]
```

What I want to be displayed is:

```
Bot is ready for duty!
Exchange Cog is ready!
Waiting for loop!
Loop Starting!
243
```

(That number changes every day, that's why I can't just use it once.)

If anyone knows how I would be able to work this out, please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like url needs a login to get access to the content. I can't check if the xpath is accurate or provide a different solution. can you post the html source of the page and the element you are looking at?

Comment: Here is the source of the website: https://pastebin.com/2PQsb5Sk
What I am trying to get is: <h4 class="margin-none font-color padding-5px bg-background border-radius display-inline" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="246 Rubies Available" aria-describedby="tooltip479342">246</h4>

Comment: The expressions in your question ("Loop Starting!", etc.) aren't in the html.

Comment: Loop Starting is just there so I know the loop started.

Comment: The parts:
Bot is ready for duty!
Exchange Cog is ready!
Waiting for loop!
Loop Starting!
 Aren't in HTML cuz they are apart of loading my discord bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tree` has 7 `<h4>` tags that meet the description in your comment. If I understand you correctly, in order to get all 7, you can use this:

```
stuff = tree.xpath('//h4[@data-toggle="tooltip"]')
for s in stuff:
    print(s.text)
```

The output is:

```
246
2
7
16
1
1
1
```

If you know ahead of time that your target number (like `246` in this `tree`) is always the first, you can even shorten this to:

```
stuff = tree.xpath('//h4[@data-toggle="tooltip"]')[0]
print(stuff.text)
```

and the output will be:

```
246
```

Comment: Thank you! As seen from this image: https://prnt.sc/s5xl7f I want to scrap that 246 (currently it is 247) and that "7". Will figure the 7 out, but the things you mentioned (246
2
7
16
1
1
1) What are those? I don't see any 2s, 7s etc...

Comment: Figured it out, they are other rates for community market.

Comment: Also, is there any way you can click on elements via bs4?

Comment: @LukaBedić Neither bs4 nor lxml can click on elements. For that you need something like selenium.

Comment: Well it is a discord bot, selenium opens browser on the windows itself, if I buy a VPS for example, can it run selenium for me to login?

Comment: @LukaBedić I really don't know. I believe the best way for you to handle it is to post it as a new question with different tags, so those most familiar with these issue can see it. It's also SO policy that questions only address one issue at a time...